# why data config execute in server and browser in nuxt

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

Can anyone help me out?
I find the log both server and browser,is this necessary?

```
export default {
    data(){
       console.log('I'm data');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because

- your data gets used on the server for rendering your app/component
- your data gets made available and reactive in the client for your app/component to work as expected

Let me know if something is unclear, I could try to explain it in more detail.

Comment: thank you very much!
I don't understand [data gets made available and reactive in the client for your app/component to work as expected]. In my opinion，data computed on server and the client just use the computed result ,the repeated calculation  is a waste.